# Parameter number 2 is not an OUT parameter

Tags: java, mysql, sql, stored-procedures, callable-statement

```
String sqlString = "{CALL MyStoredProcedure(?,?)}";

CallableStatement sqlStm = connection.prepareCall(sqlString);

sqlStm.setString(1, username);
sqlStm.registerOutParameter(2, Types.DECIMAL, 0); // <---- ERROR
sqlStm.execute();
```

This is my error stacktrace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter number 2 is not an OUT parameter
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.checkIsOutputParam(CallableStatement.java:690)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.registerOutParameter(CallableStatement.java:1881)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.registerOutParameter(CallableStatement.java:1890)
    at com.isb.igt.database.StoredProcedures.preparationCalls(StoredProcedures.java:40)
    at com.isb.igt.database.StoredProcedures.main(StoredProcedures.java:236)
```

The procedure first line:

> CREATE DEFINER=devel@11.22.33.44 PROCEDURE MyStoredProcedure(IN login
>   VARCHAR(255), OUT variable DECIMAL(20,2)

I can't figure out how to get it to work.

Thank you

Comment: You need a variable if you want to store the result.

Comment: what does the definition for `MyStoredProcedure` look like?

Comment: Where is the definition of the procedure being called?!

Comment: CREATE DEFINER=`devel`@`11.22.33.44` PROCEDURE `MyStoredProcedure`(IN `login` VARCHAR(255), OUT `variable` DECIMAL(20,2)

I'mnot even reaching the execute line, i.e. the mysql instance with this, I though the definition is not important.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.sql.SQLException: Parameter number X is not an OUT parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017934/java-sql-sqlexception-parameter-number-x-is-not-an-out-parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function call should look like `{? = call MyStoredProcedure(?)}`

Comment: Thx, in this case, how do I send the 'login' IN parameter ?

Comment: same as you did previously, but parameter 1 would be OUT, parameter 2 would be IN

Comment: FUNCTION MyStoredProcedure does not exist

Comment: So maybe you should create a `function`, not `procedure`? or some namespace issue

Comment: mysql part is not under my control, I need to call a procedure and the prepareCall just creates this:

    SELECT MyStoredProcedures('name')

Comment: This worked for me. I could never get it work as a stored procedure with an OUT parameter (although, the procedure works fine through MySQL Workbench). So, I changed to a stored function.